# Custom layouts for custom post types? (wordpress)

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm intending to have a few different custom post types but I want them to have different layouts to that of the normal posts.

Normal posts have two different appearances themselves, one for the index page and one for when you click through to the permalink page.

For custom posts I want to do the same thing (two different layouts, both different from normal posts) but for some reason my code doesn't seem to be making a difference.

I've so far used custom post template plugin as well as tried to code in a post-[postype].php file, but both seemed ineffective.

For my single.php here's what the code is -

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!--- post wrapper home/post --->   
<?php if ( is_home()) { echo '<div class="fullposthome">' ; } 

else {  echo '<div class="fullpost">' ; }
?>

<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imgtest', true) ) { ?> <!--- made following div appear if said custom field presetn ---->
<div class="testbox"><img src="<?php the_field('imgtest'); ?>" alt="" width="100%" height="auto"/></div> <!--- div with custom field inside --->
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_home()) { echo '<div class="contenttextboxhome">' ; } 

else {  echo '<div class="contenttextbox">' ; }
?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

</div>  

        <?php temptheme1_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                comments_template();
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!--- post wrapper --->

</div><!-- #primary -->
```

For custom posts I've tried changing the line 
for custom posts I tried  as that is what I'm assuming the names are referencing [content/single.php]
 - this is in underscore.me / _S framework mind you, I'm also going to try on Thematic framework but since _S is more bare bones it would be easier for me to build it how I want it.

So my question I guess is where am I going wrong with my coding or how do I use the Custom Post Template plug in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom post type is "products"

then

1. Archive file should be : archive-products.php
2. Taxonomy should be : taxonomy-product_category_slug.php
3. Single file should be : single-products.php

if you want different content template then

create file of like content-product.php

and in your single.php use `get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`

For current situation if everything working fine then just create content file, customize it.

Comment: I already have a content file though? I'll be trying this method but do I not want to make a separate file from content.php since it is already being used?

Comment: If you want to change the structure of your custom post only then you have to create another conten-{custom-post}.php

Comment: how should i reference it (content-movies) in the php? as its currently { 'content', 'movies'} and would become {'movies','movie'}

Comment: so far I have got a custom look on my permalink page but not a custom look on the index page (for the custom-post-type post)

Comment: if you are using `get_template_part( 'content', 'movies' );` in your single.php and if the **content-movies.php** is not present in your directory it will look for **content.php** file.

For a instance just copy your content-single.php and save it as content-movies.php and replace your `get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );` to `get_template_part( 'content', 'movies' );` in single.php

Comment: I had to switch to Thematic to get it to work as far as it has also but I'm unsure of the index styling files path for the theme, in the single.php some code in it reads "echo apply_filters( 'thematic_open_id_content', '<div id="content">' . "\n\n" );"